# Why doesn't my javascript onclick work with div?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to turn a `<div>` into a link to local HTML document (./lilo/index.html) using JavaScript.

#### HTML

```
<div class="pagelist_item" onClick="goto("./lilo")">
    <h4>Test Button</h4>
    <h6>Discription</h6>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function goto(url){
    window.location = url;
    alert(url);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6HHTd/

But when I click the button, nothing happens.

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quotes are incorrect in this line:

```
<div class="pagelist_item" onClick="goto("./lilo")">
```

jsfiddle even shows the error in red text.

Using apostrophes makes it easier to fix:

```
<div class="pagelist_item" onClick="goto('./lilo')">
```

To clarify, in `"hi "there" you"` the second double-quote matches with the first, closing the string and causing an error with the rest of the expression. Escaping the quotes with back-slashes works `"hi \"there\" you"` but embedding apostrophes (single-quotes) within double-quotes is often easier. (JavaScript is happy to use either single or double-quotes to delimit strings.)

Also rename your function from `goto`, as it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: As the question was "why does my JavaScript not work" then I would suggest that it is an answer.

Comment: @harsha yes it is an answer.

Comment: @DobbyIsDead: to clarify andy's response, you can't use goto as a function name, it is a keyword reserved for future use in javascript which cannot be used as an identifier.

Comment: Thank you @JoeMinichino. Someone else mentioned that it was a keyword but their comment disappeared. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery as follows

```
$('.pagelist_item').click(function(){
     window.location="./lilo";
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk74F/2/)